# with or without a comma: "my close friend John"

Tags: punctuation, appositives

I'm wondering if the following sentences are both OK. If so, what's the difference?

> The one you saw is my close friend, John.

> The one you saw is my close friend John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma makes it non-restrictive. What precedes it is a sufficiently restricted descriptor. For a definite noun phrase, that means it has a unique referent. Therefore, you have only one close friend. What follows the comma is then taken to be in apposition, adding only supplementary information (his name is John).

Without a comma, the name becomes part of the descriptor, necessary to fully restrict the set of possible referents. So you have more than one close friend, and you mean the one whose name is John.

Comment: I see people writing 'his wife Sarah" (without a comma), but that doesn't seem to imply the person has more than one wife.

Comment: @Apollyon Very good observation. There are a few exceptions and they're mostly family relations. Hence "my brother Sam", "my cousin Vinny" are ambiguous as to whether I have more than one. Also, sometimes context is enough to pick out one referent and then you might well intend an apposition: "I'd like you to meet my associate, Rita" (with a definite pause before the name) when the speaker has more than one associate, but Rita is with him in the room, so she's clearly the unique referent intended.